# Group a list of strings by the first n letters

Tags: clojure

I have a collection of strings like

```
["snowy10" "catty20" "manny20" "snowy20" "catty10" "snowy20" "catty30" "manny10" "snowy20"  "manny30"]
```

Would like it to be converted to a collection of collections grouped on the  basis of the first five characters of the string.

```
[["snowy10" "snowy20" "snowy20"] ["catty10" "catty20""catty30"]["manny10" ""manny20""  "manny20"]]
```

Looking for a solution in Clojure.

Comment: These category names, are they known in advance? Is it a fixed set, or can they be anything?

Answer (score 5):

The [`group-by`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/group-by) function is helpful here:

> ```
> clojure.core/group-by
> ([f coll])
>   Returns a map of the elements of coll keyed by the result of
>   f on each element. The value at each key will be a vector of the
>   corresponding elements, in the order they appeared in coll.
> ```

In other words, `group-by` uses the given function `f` to produce a key for each element in `coll`, and the value associated with that key is a vector of accumulated elements for that key.

In your example, if we know all input strings are guaranteed to have at least 5 characters, then we can use [`subs`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/subs).  But it's easier to construct a robust solution that is more general using [`take`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/take):

```clj
(def strings ["snowy10" "catty20" "manny20" "snowy20" "catty10" "snowy20" "catty30" "manny10" "snowy20"  "manny30"])

(group-by (partial take 5) strings)
```

gives us:

```
{(\s \n \o \w \y) ["snowy10" "snowy20" "snowy20" "snowy20"]
 (\c \a \t \t \y) ["catty20" "catty10" "catty30"]
 (\m \a \n \n \y) ["manny20" "manny10" "manny30"]}
```

This isn't quite what we want -- we just want the map values.  For that, we use [`vals`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/vals):

```clj
(-> (group-by (partial take 5) strings)
    (vals))
```

and we get:

```
(["snowy10" "snowy20" "snowy20" "snowy20"]
 ["catty20" "catty10" "catty30"]
 ["manny20" "manny10" "manny30"])
```

Changing the grouping criteria is as simple as changing the "key" function we provide to `group-by`.  For example, we can group by the last two characters in each string by using [`take-last`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/take-last):

```clj
(-> (group-by (partial take-last 2) strings)
    (vals))
```

which gives:

```
(["snowy10" "catty10" "manny10"]
 ["catty20" "manny20" "snowy20" "snowy20" "snowy20"]
 ["catty30" "manny30"])
```

Comment: For efficiency, you can use `#(subs % 0 (min 5 (count %)))` as the key function.

Answer (score 3):

```
user> (def v ["snowy10" "catty20" "manny20" "snowy20" "catty10" "snowy20" "catty30" "manny10" "snowy20"  "manny30"])
#'user/v

user> (vals (group-by #(subs % 0 5) v))
(["snowy10" "snowy20" "snowy20" "snowy20"]
 ["catty20" "catty10" "catty30"]
 ["manny20" "manny10" "manny30"])
```

Comment: Thank you. what if the substrings that I want to group by are not at the beginning of the string?  like  ["aaasnowy10" "nasascatty20" "asasmanny20" "asasmsnowy20" "rfrdrdcatty10" "yaassnowy20" "uhnjacatty30" "uhuhumanny10" "jnnnksnowy20"  "uinjnmanny30"]
W

Comment: Are they in a known location? Always starting in the same position within the string and having the same length?

Comment: Yes & No. would appreciate solutions to both actually. Thanks

Comment: If there is some rule for finding the substrings (e.g., the last n characters of the string) it's easy.  If not, but you have a list of the substrings to search for (either hard-coded or acquired dynamically somehow) it's not too hard. If neither of those, and you have to 'discover' common substrings among the original set, that's much harder --- for that last case I suggest opening a new question.

Answer (score 1):

how about split string by `\d`, like this:

```
user=> (def v ["snowy10" "catty20" "manny20" "snowy20" "catty10" "snowy20" "catty30" "manny10" "snowy20"  "manny30"])
#'user/v
user=> (vals (group-by #(first (clojure.string/split % #"\d")) v))
(["snowy10" "snowy20" "snowy20" "snowy20"] 
 ["catty20" "catty10" "catty30"] 
 ["manny20" "manny10" "manny30"])
```